# Quoting HTML tags for padding

Tags: org-mode, org-export, html

I've got this working fine

```
@@html:<font color = "#4715b3">@@
$0$ is a natural number.
@@html:</font>@@
```

and this too

```
@@html:<b>@@bold text@@html:</b>@@
```

but this, my best guess at how to indent the text in 20px, is not working

```
@@html:<padding left = "20px">@@
$0$ is a natural number.
@@html:</padding>@@
```

I can't use the html source block because it doesn't see the MathJax/Latex. Is this possible with [Quoting HTML tags](https://orgmode.org/manual/Quoting-HTML-tags.html)?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no HTML tag called `padding`. I would go backwards: write HTML that produces what you want and then figure out how to write the Org mode to produce that.

Comment: `<h2 style="padding-top:20px; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:20px; padding-left:20px">London</h2>`

Comment: Yes, but there is no `<padding ...>` tag as in your question:  what you show in your comment is an `<h2>` tag with some style attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, you can't say `<padding ...> ... </padding>` in HTML: there is [no such tag](https://way2tutorial.com/html/tag/index.php). But as you note, you can specify a style attribute on many (most?) tags. Try e.g. a paragraph `<p style=...> ... </p>`. The following seems to work for me:

```html
    <p> Some paragraph </p>
    <p style="padding-left: 20px">
      \(0\) is a natural number.
    </p>
```

so reverse-engineering it into the Org mode form gives us:

```org
Some paragraph.

@@html:<p style="padding-left: 20px">@@
$0$ is a natural number.
@@html:</p>@@
```